# Calling C function from the x86 assembler

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to write a function that converts decimal numbers into binary in assembler. Since printing is so troublesome in there, I have decided to make a separate function in C that just prints the numbers. But when I run the code, it always prints '0110101110110100'

Heres the C function (both print and conversion):

```
void printBin(int x) {
  printf("%d", x);
}

void DecToBin(int n)
{
    // Size of an integer is assumed to be 16 bits
    for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        int k = n >> i;
        printBin(k & 1);
}
```

heres the code in asm:

```
.globl _DecToBin
.extern _printBin

_DecToBin:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp

  movl 8(%ebp),%eax
  movl $15, %ebx
  cmpl $0, %ebx
  jl end

  start:
  movl %ebx, %ecx
  movl %eax, %edx
  shrl %cl, %eax
  andl $1, %eax
  pushl %eax
  call _printBin
  movl %edx, %eax
  dec %ebx
  cmpl $0, %ebx
  jge start

  end:

  movl %ebp, %esp
  popl %ebp
  ret
```

Cant figure out where the mistake is. Any help would be appreciated

[disassembled code using online program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRpgT.png)

Comment: You shift `eax` by 15, and then never restore `eax` before the next `shr` - I don't think this has anything to do with the call to `_printBin`

Comment: What compiler are you using to compile `printBin(..)`? Depending on the compiler, the ABI may differ. What this means is that the register in which it expects to read the argument from may change. 
So, while running `gcc` with x86 as target will produce a function that expects argument `x` in register `ax`, a x86-64 target will produce a  function that expect the argument in register `rdi`.

Comment: @hlt I see, thank you for the comment. I have added "movl %eax, %edx" line after "start:" and changed %eax with %edx in further operations. But the output is still the same :/

Comment: @tsg I am using CodeBlocks 17.12

Comment: Are you compiling for a 64-bit target?

1. If you can see the compiled assembly for _printBin, you can see exactly where it expects to get its argument from. You are pushing the arg on the stack, which is normally not where functions read arguments from

2. Try putting the value of %eax in %rdi instead prior to calling _printBin

Comment: @tsg I get "bad register name" error when doing so

Comment: Then its a 32-bit target. In that case, it's a 32-bit target. `_printBin` should expect its arg in %eax. Could you post the disassembly for `_printBin`?

Comment: @tsg I have updated the original post with the picture, but it is clearly not the same assembly instructions as the ones I am using

Comment: *But when I run the code, it always prints '0110101110110100'*. What value of `n` are you passing it?

Comment: @Ach113, post the disassembly again after setting the arch to `x86` instead of `x86-64`. Also, I don't really know if CodeBlocks uses the same ABI as `gcc`

Comment: @lurker it does it for any value.

Comment: @TSG unfortunately the programs that I have found online only have x86-64

Comment: @Ach113 you need to show how you're calling it. It doesn't make sense that it would print the same thing for any value of `n`.

Comment: @lurker the fact that it doesnt make any sense is why I posted it here. I simply call it using DecToBin(n), where n is user input

Comment: @Ach113 the fact that it makes no sense is why I'm saying you haven't provided enough information. What you show makes no sense. It will make more sense if it's revealed the context in which `DecToBin` is being called.

Comment: @TSG: compiler-generated code for `_printBin` will expect its arg on the stack, not in EAX, for 32-bit.  `gcc -mregparm=1` is *not* the default on any platform.

Comment: @PeterCordes is correct. Source: https://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions . For x86-64, however, args on registers seems to be default, though

Comment: @TSG: Yes, register args are used in modern calling conventions because it's more efficient.  Just not EAX for either x86-64 System V or x64 Windows.  It would have made sense to use RAX as an arg-passing register; it's not uncommon to need `foo(bar())`. But only the Irvine32 calling convention passes an arg in EAX.  (Or like I said, gcc 32-bit `regparm`.)  x86-64 SysV does use `al` for variadic functions to indicate the number of FP args passed in XMM registers, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your principle problem is that it is very unlikely that %edx is preserved across the function call to printBin.
Also:

%ebx is not a volatile register in most (any?) C calling convention rules.  You need to check your compilers documentation and conform to it.
If you are going to use ebx, you need to save and restore it.

The stack pointer needs to be kept aligned to 16 bytes.  On my machine (macos), it SEGVs under printBin if you don’t.